# How to apply OR between all booleans in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have

`x = [false, false, true, true, false]`

I want a function that returns `true` if there's at least one `true` in the array, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7uVWk/

```
x = [false, false, true, true, false];

function hasTrue(x) {
  result = false;
  ​for (var i=0; i <​x.length; i++) {
    result = result || x[i];
  }
}  
document.write(hasTrue(result));
```

How can I achieve this result more succinctly?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I like Python too! Just right now I'm wrestling with node.js. It's quite a change of pace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (I did not write a separate function, because this syntax does already make much sense):

```
var x = [false, false, true, true, false];
x.some(function(val) {
    return val === true;
}); // true or false. In this case, true
```

Comment: I've never seen that method used before, any idea how well supported it is cross browser?

Comment: @JamesGaunt See the linked documentation. It also includes a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility).

Comment: +1 This shows explicitly the use of `.some()`, but in practice you could just do `return val;`, or better, or shorter anyway, `x.some(Boolean)`.

Comment: @RobW Since the .some implementation is beyond my comprehension, I wonder how the .some approach performs compared to leaving a for loop when a true is found. Wait, I think they're the same.

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo It can easily be tested at http://jsperf.com/. Bonus: If you are [developing for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8#Expression_closures_(Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection)), the code can also be reduced to: **`x.some(function(val)val)`**.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could quit the loop when you find your first true:

```
x = [false, false, true, true, false];

function hasTrue(x) {
  ​for (var i=0; i <​x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i]) return true;
  }
  return false;
}  
document.write(hasTrue(result));
```

Is that succinct enough?

Answer (score 2):

Logically or'ing all elements in an array is equivalent to just one of them being true. The following function would be much more efficient:

```
function arrayHasTrue(x_)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < x_.length; ++i)
    {
        if(x_[ i ])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This might skip the first value since you're doing `++i`

Comment: Not true, the third expression of a `for` loop isn't evaluated until after the first iteration.

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why I said *might*, and yeah, this doesn't skip anything

Comment: One should be careful in using "mights" and "maybes" in the context of well-defined programming languages; it implies undefined behavior and often leads to unnecessary checks that can, in the right circumstances, affect the performance of a system. In the case of `for` loops, the behavior of the third expression is *well-defined*. It should also be noted that the prefix increment/decrement operators are sometimes faster than postfix increment/decrement operators (but *never* slower).

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion:

```
function hasTrue(x) {
  return x.length == 1 ? x[0] : x[0] || hasTrue(x.slice(1));
}
```

Comment: That's going to waste a lot of time copying `x` if it is long.

Comment: @KevinReid: Yes, of course, but the OP didn't ask for a fast solution. Did you downvote the answer because it doesn't meet some criteria that you invented yourself?

Comment: Sure. I think it's unwise to present such code without noting its disadvantages in case someone decides to use it outside of the original context. Also, the OP didn't say "Nothing but succinctness matters."